# Spring Scheduler/Threading working doesnt work on centos minimal

Tags: java, linux, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I created a spring boot app which has a  scheduler which runs every X seconds

Main Class :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    public class FiobenchmarkApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(FiobenchmarkApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
```

My Spring Scheduler class is as below

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Scheduler {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
    public void getFioResult(){
System.out.println("hello class");
}

}
```

After gradle clean build I get a jar named:fiobench.jar

The application runs perfectly and calls the scheduler every X seconds when I run on my local machine(Which is ubuntu)

When the jar is transfered to another machine (Centos 7 Minimal and both ubutnu and centos have same Java versions ) .

The scheduler is called only once at the start and is never called after it calls one time .

Has any one faced any such issue with spring scheduler.

Also When I try to replicate the same using normal java multi threading it doesnt work on centos minimal while it works on my ubuntu machine

Below is my pure java implementation of thread

```
public class Scheduler extends Thread implements Runnable{

    //@Scheduled(fixedRate=1000)
    public  void getFioResult(){


}

@Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while(true){

            try {
                getFioResult();
                Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
```

And my main class is

```
public class FiobenchmarkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scheduler s=new Scheduler();
        s.start();


    }
}
```

Comment: Try to print more logs by enabling debug mode.